# Как сделать авторизацию на Javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript, ajax, php

Есть php скрипт на сервере (http://example.com/login.php), который при успехе высвечивает OK, а при неудаче Error. Используется post запрос и отправляются следующие параметры: login, password. Помогите написать javascript-код, который бы отправлял эти параметры на сервер, и в случае успеха переадресовывал пользователя на страницу ma.html, а в случае неудачи высвечивал бы сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А почему нельзя отправить стандартными средствами эти данные (просто создав правильную форму)

```
<form action="http://example.com/login.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login" id="login" />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

А проверив данные скриптом login.php сделать редирект или вывод ошибки?
Но если так хотите, то вот на аяксе код который решает вашу проблемму:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    data: "name="+$("#login").val()+"&pass="+$("#pass").val(),
    success: function(reply){
      if (reply == 'Ok') {
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/ma.html";
      } else {
        window.alert(reply);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Форма данная выше подходит к этому скрипту за исключением того что вам нужно убрать параметры формы, action и method. Ну и кнопке убрать тип...

Comment: обычный html не подходит, т.к. скрипт выполняется в приложение на клиентском компе. твой пример у меня почему-то не работает

Comment: @Лёва Черненко, подключили jquery? Что в консоли есть?

UPD (через 25 минут):
http://j290065.myjino.ru/ вот пример ваш. Откройте код и смотрите.
Файл login.php возвращает "ОК" если логин/пароль = admin/admin и "Егор" во всех остальных случаях

Comment: все, понял я свою ошибку. спасибо большое. p.s. прости дурака, в js полный ноль :)